# Use java 8 stream api to do deep copy of array list but get build time error

Tags: java, java-8, lombok

I use *[lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/all)* library in my spring-boot project's model classes.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {

    private String fullname;
    private long someNumber;
    private boolean isManager;
}
```

In another class, I have a list of employees:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = getListOfEmployees();
```

I would like to create a deep copy of the `employeeList`, the following things are what I tried:

step 1. I create a copy constructor in `Employee` class:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {

    private String fullname;
    private long someNumber;
    private boolean isManager;

    // copy constructor
    public Employee(Employee employee) {
        this.fullname = employee.fullname;
        this.someNumber = employee.someNumber;
        this.isManager = employee.isManager;
    }
}
```

step 2. I use Java 8 stream API to create a deep copy of the list of employees:

```
List<Employee> employeeListCopy = employeeList.stream().map(Employee::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But when I build my sprint-boot project, I got error:

```
Error:(13, 1) java: constructor Employee in class com.my.webapp.model.Employee cannot be applied to given types;
  required: com.my.webapp.Employee
  found: java.lang.String,long,boolean
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Why? How to get rid of this error for my deep copy?

Comment: ```Employee::new```does requires parameters, not sure this reference api but try such:```Employee::new(it)``` or ```new Employee(it)```

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos that gives compiler error, please have a try.

Comment: OK, so:
```stream().map(it -> new Employee(it))``` does it solves it for you?

Comment: No, please see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the Stream API, but in `lombok`. When you use `@Builder`, there will be a call to a constructor:

```
public Employee build() {
      return new Employee(fullname, someNumber, isManager);
}
```

from within `EmployeeBuilder` (that lombok will generate). Since you have already provided a constructor, lombok will not generate another one (i.e.: lombok will *only* generate the needed constructor for the Builder IFF there is not a constructor already defined). The solution is rather simple, add `@AllArgsConstructor` to your class.

In general, I personally, am not a fan of `@Builder`, I use `@Accessors(chain = true)` instead:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Accessors(chain = true)
static class Employee {

    private String fullname;
    private long someNumber;
    private boolean isManager;

    public Employee() {

    }

    // copy constructor
    public Employee(Employee employee) {
        fullname = employee.fullname;
        someNumber = employee.someNumber;
        isManager = employee.isManager;
    }
}
```

And you can do:

```
Employee emp = new Employee()
        .setFullname("")
        .setManager(false)
        .setSomeNumber(2L);
```

Comment: Yep, I guessed it should be the lombok caused issue. I didn't realize it is this one. Thanks!